# How long do you have to let your Dwellers Explore the Wasteland before they start to find good gear?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The longest I've allowed a Dweller to explore the Wasteland is 12 hours and they're still only finding BB Guns and other useless junk. So, how do you usually equip your explorers, how many do you send out at once, how long do you let them roam the Wastes, and what are their stats?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224161/which-stats-gear-can-get-the-best-our-of-wasteland-exploration?rq=1 The answer to this question is pretty much the same as this question.

Comment: @two bugs I don't think that's true at all

Answer (score 9):

As pointed at in this question here, the luck of your wanderers has an impact on what they will find. Honestly from observations luck has More of an impact than time to get nice gear but time is still a factor to get Great gear.

My longest runs so far are around 36 hours of exploration and 18 hours return trip.

The low level luck people I used to send out would still bring back rusty whatever guns and BB guns even towards the end of their trips. They did some times come back with a nice rifle or the like but that was rare.

The high level luck people I have started using are amazing. They still find rusty guns and BB guns but they are also finding rail guns and power armor. This is making me definitely focus more on luck for pretty much everyone in the game.

To answer the general questions that followed, I send between 1 and 6 people out at once, I try to make their trips last as long as I can by loading them down with Stimpacks and RadAways. For stats I focus on Strength, Perception, Endurance and Luck. These stats appear to help them last longer and fear encounters less as well give an upturn as to what items they are bringing back with them.

NOTE: The -huge- majority of my guys WILL die before I bring them back as I can not check in on them as often as I should. Every time the amount of caps and gear on them greatly out-weights the cost of the revival (as its over 1000 now for them).

Comment: I tend to not focus on endurance as much as the other 3 since there's armors giving a lot of endurance (+5) compared to the other stats. Luck is the hardest to get higher with a armor that will make your explorer last longer.

Comment: What do you consider high luck? The ability to train luck  comes pretty late in the game. Is high luck anything over 3? 2?

Comment: @intuited 6+. While the new update makes survival a bit harder in an old vault I have so many 10 luckers now its not even funny. There are only so many rooms and so many people

Comment: Maybe the stage of the game you are at also affects this. I just sent someone with luck over 10 out for about 15 hours and and someone with luck about 8 out for over 20 and they didn't find anything different from the things I usually find. I did notice that the monsters they fought got considerably more difficult, with rate of stimpack usage increasing markedly. I've got 34 Dwellers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the chance of the rare items, but I can recommend you to open equip your wanderers with lots of cool gear and then leave them overnight. Most likely they can defend themselves and so they can get cool stuff like Lockboxes. I don't know if it will work for you, but it worked for me.