# Consistently worthless items

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I tried this experiment: I leveled an already legendary dweller to her max SPECIAL. Everything is 10. Took a while, and required solid training facilities and allot of checking in at specific times to get her started for the new training cycle, but there you go, she's perfect.

Anyway, I sent her out into the wasteland with a power armor (why, I don't know exactly, it doesn't boost anything), a tuned alien blaster (18-20, the best weapon I have) and the max stack of stimpacks and radaway (25).

After 34 hours in the wasteland (will be more next time, but she started out low-level because she was in training facilities the whole time) but my conclusion is that I can only find crap items.

The money is great, don't get me wrong, she is returning home as we speak with little over 4000 caps. But why, for the life of me, are the items so crap?? Still bb-guns, 10mm's, a bunch of shotguns and rifles, and all the low level suits I already have a bunch of.

C'mon ! Where's the plasma guns !? the power armors !? Has anyone ever found really good loot? Like the MIRV or something? (so *not* from a lunchbox but from the wasteland obviously).

**Update** My question is not entirely the same as the "What best gear/stats ... " question, since the point of my question was that I already maxed out the values of SPECIAL and gear. (gear being *almost* the best weapon). I am curious what the loot mechanism behind the game is when after the fact that you are maxing out, you're still receiving sub-standard loot.

Comment: [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223904/61395) should help you send out the best dweller you have.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau that question only covers the best dweller SPECIAL stats. As I indicate, mine are all 10, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which stats / gear can get the best our of wasteland exploration?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224161/which-stats-gear-can-get-the-best-our-of-wasteland-exploration)

Comment: @Ionic elaborated on the nature of the question

Comment: Your edit isn't really on-topic -- remember, Arqade is not a forum. Discussion like that is fine in chat, but not on main site.

Comment: @Schism I see what you're saying and think you have a point. I've removed the edit. My question doesn't invite users to _'share a story'_ anymore.

Comment: This annoys me. I've equipped all 200 of my dwellers with *minimum* level 7 lasers (many with level 14+) and level 3+ gear, and my explorers still have to drag truckloads of level 0 BB guns and level 1 gear that I have to get rid of.

Answer (score 7):

The quality of items you find is directly tied to the length of time the dweller is out in the wasteland. Their survivability of course is related to their level (health) and the number of stims/radaways you give them.

Basically just wait longer. The longer they are out there, the better chance of getting a better drop. There are no guarantees of course, but if they can survive out there for several more days, leave them for as long as you can and you should get better drops. Since they take no damage or radiation while on their way back, you can wait until they are literally 1 hp away from death before recalling them to get maximum exploration time.

Comment: So the SPECIAL does nothing and it would be better to send an untrained person?

Comment: Luck helps getting better gear, perception helps find abandoned buildings, strength helps opening boxes. See [what each special does](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/what-does-each-special-stat-in-fallout-shelter-do). Time is a factor but not the sole one.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, since staying out there longer and given more chance to play the statistics is most likely the only explanation to the question. Apparently maxing out and bring the best weapon has influences the statistics. I would however like to here from someone who _has_ found really good items !!

Comment: Best weapon helps kill baddies that are otherwise attempting to kill your dweller. This contributes to letting your dweller stay out for longer.

Comment: The only two really nice weapons I've found so far came along with legendary dwellers (Bittercup and Alistair Tenpenny) whom I received from lunchbox cards. I've yet to find a weapon in the wild better than 6-8 damage.

Comment: Update -- left my highest level dweller out for 2 days and 12 hours, and he found a "Wazer Wifle", which was the best found-weapon in the game for me so far. Given the time, I'd say that the duration has the biggest impact on their chances of finding quality items.

Comment: Others have said that they've found some great items, but only after leaving the dwellers out for more than a day and a half. So I have to agree with Tim: *Basically just wait longer.*

Answer (score 3):

A person here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3awycu/chance_at_a_legendary_comes_just_after_hour_60/

says that after hour 60 you get a chance of getting legendary item, then you might or might not succeed opening the crate with the item.

Here is what he says:

> I got my first two legendary items from the Wasteland today. Appears
>   that the event is set to occur shortly after 2 and half days out from
>   the vault. While it appears the event will always occur - based on the
>   four screenshots below - success isn't guaranteed. If I had to guess,
>   it is probably based on Agility - Lockpicking is based on Agility if I
>   recall - but I'll have to take a closer look at the stats of the two
>   people who succeeded.
>
> ```
> National Guard Depot - Success 1 [1]
> National Guard Depot - Success 2 [2]
> National Guard Depot - Failure 1 [3]
> National Guard Depot - Failure 2 [4]
> ```
>
> This is not to say that this is the only chance at a Legendary. This
>   is just the only one I've managed to identify so far. I got lucky by
>   having two of them drop so close together and being able to capture
>   the logs. That they both occurred so soon after the 60 hour mark led
>   me to watch for the event in my other two explorers who were
>   approaching that mark.
>
> Now that I know that an event can be associated with a specific time,
>   there are a few other events I've identified associated with Rare
>   drops that I can check to see if they occur with some regularity.

Answer (score 0):

I sent out a mid level dweller that I got from a lunchbox card (Stephen Jones?) who had 7 Luck i believe. Found a Mirv in the wastes within about 10 minutes of leaving the vault. Miracle indeed but proof that what you find is essentially a roll of the dice.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally random, I sent a bunch of 1 level dwellers with no special skills and no stimpacks what so ever out trying to kill them off cause my vault was full. As I was checking if they are dead yet so I can remove them I saw that some of them where still alive. Reason one of them had found the MIRV, another the gauss and so on and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The more you explore, the better the items. 34 hours is a *very* small amount of time, if you hope to get something good. Half a month is something, though...
**Also note that after 30 Days, ± 15 Minutes, your Dweller will encounter a special Location, from which a Legendary item is almost guaranteed.**

Answer (score -3):

You sure can find legendary gear. I found gattling laser almost immediately when sending out a legendary dweller for the first time. You can cheat of course if you change your time forward a week load the game change it back load the game and send some one out they won't encounter anything for a whole week then they have full stim packs and 7 days on the timer when they start to loot.